# Django Auth: Use external service (without Django-social-app)

Tags: python, django, facebook, gmail, hotmail

- How could I do to allow users to link their Gmail or Facebook account in my Django App ?

I'd like to avoid my clients to register in my site if they have an account in any of the common sites (Gmail, Facebook etc...)

I know the app **Django Social Auth** can be used for this purposes but I'd like to know **how to do this auth by my own**.

- Can anyone point me to some documentation or small example ?

I'd like to do this kind of authentication by my own, without external app, I'm looking for information not anybody to solve my code

Thanks

Comment: You may try to understand how `python-social-auth` works (https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth). [Here](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/) is an example on how to use it.

Comment: @aldo_vw I was wondering about doing this by my own but I'm thankful because your link is very useful! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can try to find an example how to use OAuth2 technology in Django from different django app. I use [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2) and you can try to copy some techniques from them.